# object as tags in Bootstrap tags input

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap Tags Input
https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

Now I want the value as id and text as city

my code:

```
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="test();" value="enter"/>
<input type="text" value="" id="test" data-role="tagsinput" />

<script>
    function test(){
        var elt = $('#test');
        elt.tagsinput({
            itemValue: 'value',
            itemText: 'text',
        });
        elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 1, "text": "Amsterdam"});
        elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 4, "text": "Washington"});
        elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 7, "text": "Sydney"});
        elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 10, "text": "Beijing"});
        elt.tagsinput('add', { "value": 13, "text": "Cairo"});
    }
</script>
```

When I hit the button, it wouldn't put the tags into the input.

Comment: Y u no indent your code

Comment: @onzinsky what do you mean?

Comment: @onzinsky They did indent their code, I'm not sure what you are getting at or why it's important here.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek If I copy paste it all, it wouldn't work either.

I think it's all for the typeahead only, I doesn't need that in my application.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek they did it afterwards. I wasn't rude or anything, and didn't down vote.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek plus he didn't someone else did